# knockoutjs get count of items that meet a condition

Tags: html, knockout.js

I have a view model that has an observable array in it which inside has an observable array.  I want to keep track when users check items off their lists.  I have the following view model and html:

```
var mydata = {
        Incomplete: ko.computed(function () {
           // return the count of items that are not IsActive
        }),
        Categories: ko.observable([
              {
                  Description: "Dairy", ListItems: ko.observableArray([
                  { Description: "Eggs", Quantity: "1 Dz.", IsActive: ko.observable(false) },
                   { Description: "Milk", Quantity: "1 Gallon", IsActive: ko.observable(false) }
                  ])
              },
              {
                  Description: "Produce", ListItems: ko.observableArray([
                      { Description: "Lettuce", Quantity: "1 Head", IsActive: ko.observable(false) },
                      { Description: "Oranges", Quantity: "5 ea.", IsActive: ko.observable(false) },
                      { Description: "Greenbeans", Quantity: "1 Thingy", IsActive: ko.observable(false) },
                  ])
              },
        ])
    };

<div data-bind="foreach: Categories" id="list-items">
            <h3 data-bind="text: Description" id="list-heading"></h3>
            <ul data-bind="foreach: ListItems">
                <li>
                    <div class="title">
                        <input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: IsActive"/>
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Quantity, disable: IsActive" class="input-readonly" readonly />
                        <input type="text" data-bind="value: Description, disable: IsActive" class="input-readonly" readonly />
                    </div>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div >
            <span data-bind="text: Incomplete"></span>
            <span >Items left in your list</span>
        </div>
```

Comment: I don't know what to do with the computed value.  I thought that I could just loop through the Categories and count the items that are not IsActive but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With your current code, you would want to loop through the categories and then for each category loop through the individual items.  Here is one possible implementation:

```
Incomplete: ko.computed(function () {
    var count = 0;
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(mydata.Categories(), function(category) {
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(category.ListItems(), function(item) {
             if (!item.IsActive()) {
                  count++;
             }
        });
    });

    return count;
}),
```

Comment: okay I think I understand this but in my console I get a Categories is not defined error which was happening when I tried to loop through the array as well.

Comment: computeds are evaluated immediately, by default, so if you define one within an object literal it is evaluated before the object exists yet. So, you can either create the computed later (add `myData.Incomplete` after the initial object is created) or pass the `deferEvaluation: true` flag in to prevent it from running until bound like: http://jsfiddle.net/rniemeyer/B8Y84/

Comment: OHHH.  Damn, okay that makes sense.  Thanks for the help man.  Truly a life saver in this situation.